# how to check if a tag is the last one

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium and Java to write a test. I have the DOM below:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <th>Copy</th>
    <th>Subfield</th>
    <th>Subfield Border</th>
    <th>Field</th>
    <th>Field Border</th>
</tr>
<tr id="333877">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="" class="copySubfieldBorderCheck"/>
    </td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td class="s">No</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>as</th>
    <th>er</th>
    <th>df</th>
    <th>xc</th>
    <th>xc</th>
</tr>
<tr id="333877">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="" class="copySubfieldBorderCheck"/>
    </td>
    <td>rt</td>
    <td class="noBorderBoldRed">Yes</td>
    <td>ff</td>
    <td>sdf</td>
</tr>
```

I want to get the `tr` that has a `td` tag whose text is `No` and alos it LAST `td` tag's text is `Yes`

I am looking for something like this:

`//tr[./td[text()='No'] and ./td[text()='Yes' and isLast()]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way would be to `concat` the 3rd and the last cell and then filter the text on `NoYes`:

```
//tr[concat(td[3], td[last()])='NoYes']
```